# Cannot acces a disposed object with Multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio

I'am getting an really annoying error every time I close my application, the error tells me:

> Cannot access a disposed object

That only happens when I close my application.

This is the part code where the error occurs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method that shows a log to the user, about what is happening behind scenes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="logtext"></param>
public void DisplayLog(string logtext)
{
    if (this.txtLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                txtLog.AppendText(logtext + "\n\n");
            }));
    }
    else
    {
        txtLog.AppendText(logtext + "\n\n");
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the `txtLog.AppendText` between the else brackets.
It could have something to do with the threads I'am using, the code above is not running within a thread that I created, only the windows forms thread that is running in the background to check for fired events, the code that is sending the `logtext` towards this method is in another internal class called `Serial`, and then it runs from a thread, does anybody have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What actually is the type of `txtLog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [`IsDisposed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed.aspx) property of the TextBox before using it:

```
if (!txtLog.IsDisposed) {
    txtLog.AppendText(logtext + "\n\n");
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it does work, thank you.

Comment: @Mobstaa Dispose can only be called on the UI thread, and this code is executing on the UI thread, too, so there should be no race conditions. But don't forget to insert that check before *both* calls to `AppendText`.